# Only create file if http status 200 with wget?

Tags: wget

I have been trying to figure out a way to make wget only create a file if the actual download response is valid, meaning no 404 or 500 status code, only 200.

However, when using the -O option (to specify filename) it will always create the file, with the content of the error page, and I haven't found a way to specify that it should ignore it if it recieves a 404 response-header.

Do I need to check the exit-code and pipe the output or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Perhaps this is the only answer, other than patching wget (a valid option):

```
wget -O somefile.html http://example.com/ || rm somefile.html
```

Comment: Good solution. Altough I might have something to add: I have an issue if the output file exists - wget is not able to download as the file already exists and returns an error, which runs the `rm` and reletes the file. Running the line alternates between downloading and removing the file.