# Can I use wget to check , but not download

Tags: wget

Can I use wget to check for a 404 and not actually download the resource?
If so how?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Only create file if http status 200 with wget?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649647/only-create-file-if-http-status-200-with-wget)

Answer (score 152):

There is the command line parameter `--spider` exactly for this. In this mode, wget does not download the files and its return value is zero if the resource was found and non-zero if it was not found. Try this (in your favorite shell):

```
wget -q --spider address
echo $?
```

Or if you want full output, leave the `-q` off, so just `wget --spider address`. `-nv` shows some output, but not as much as the default.

Comment: Note that `wget --spider` sends a HEAD request, not a GET.

Comment: @hammer, I'm not sure what version you might have been using, but with 1.14, `wget --spider` does a HEAD and, if successful, follows with a GET to the same URL. Thus, with the recursive option, it's useful for building the cache for a server-side website.

Answer (score 34):

If you want to check quietly via $? without the hassle of grep'ing wget's output you can use:

```
wget -q "http://blah.meh.com/my/path" -O /dev/null
```

Works even on URLs with just a path but has the disadvantage that something's really downloaded so this is not recommended when checking big files for existence.

Comment: The `--spider` arg *does* set a return code. But maybe that's because after 4 years 3 months and 7 days, the spider has got smarter.

Comment: Havn't checked it recently but wouldn't surprise me if they fixed it meanwhile.

Answer (score 21):

Yes easy.

```
wget --spider www.bluespark.co.nz
```

That will give you

```
Resolving www.bluespark.co.nz... 210.48.79.121
Connecting to www.bluespark.co.nz[210.48.79.121]:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
200 OK
```

Comment: need to store success & fail & proceed further based on that

Answer (score 18):

You can use the following option to check for the files:

```
wget --delete-after URL
```

Comment: This will still download the file

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to use the `wget` to check , but not download the target URL/file, just run:

```
wget --spider -S www.example.com
```

Answer (score -6):

If you are in a directory where only root have access to write in system. Then you can directly use  `wget www.example.com/wget-test` using a standard user account. So it will hit the url but because of having no write permission file won't be saved..
This method is working fine for me as i am using this method for a cronjob.
Thanks.

`sthx`

Comment: Shouldn't be used... Risky because permissions from system admin can change and break your intention and useless when there's a built-in flag like `--spider` which does exactly what the OP asks