# Cannot download with Curl and Wget in AWS EC2 Linux server

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-ec2, wget

I am using the EC2 server with Putty.

I want to download the latest sonar-scanner to the EC2 server.

I tried to access the download-URL using both Wget & Curl but they kept failing with the same messages.

This is the server system I use: **Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.8 (Maipo)**

- **WGET**

```
GNU Wget 1.14 built on linux-gnu.
```

```
[root@ip-10-X-X-X ~]# wget -v https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-4.7.0.2747-linux.zip
--2022-06-09 09:56:55--  https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-4.7.0.2747-linux.zip
Resolving binaries.sonarsource.com (binaries.sonarsource.com)... 99.84.191.23, 99.84.191.71, 99.84.191.75, ...
Connecting to binaries.sonarsource.com (binaries.sonarsource.com)|99.84.191.23|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

- **CURL**

```
curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0 NSS/3.44 zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.8.0
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz unix-sockets
```

```
[root@ip-10-X-X-X ~]# curl -O -v https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-4.7.0.2747-linux.zip
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* About to connect() to binaries.sonarsource.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 99.84.208.28...
* Connected to binaries.sonarsource.com (99.84.208.28) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:29 --:--:--     0* NSS error -5938 (PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR)
* Encountered end of file
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:30 --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Encountered end of file
```

I'm new with using this EC2 server. Do you know what could I do to solve this?

Thank you, any help would be really appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

- I added `-k` and `--no-check-certificate` to respectively curl & wget, but still returning the same error messages
- I tried to [check the wget connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264726/can-i-use-wget-to-check-but-not-download#:%7E:text=wget%20%2Dq%20%2D%2Dspider%20address%0Aecho%20%24%3F:%7E:text=wget%20%2Dq%20%2D%2Dspider%20address%0Aecho%20%24%3F), but it doesn't seem to work for URLs with download end-point:

```
[root@ip-10-70-10-87 settings]# wget -q --spider https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-4.7.0.2747-linux.zip
[root@ip-10-70-10-87 settings]# echo $?
4
[root@ip-10-70-10-87 settings]# wget -q --spider https://www.google.com/
[root@ip-10-70-10-87 settings]# echo $?
0
[root@ip-10-70-10-87 settings]# wget -q --spider https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.8.6/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.6-bin.tar.gz
[root@ip-10-70-10-87 settings]# echo $?
4
[root@ip-10-70-10-87 settings]# wget -q --spider https://assets.ctfassets.net/br4ichkdqihc/6jNPyoUDznu06Mk4dr9CEn/560e34fec221fad43a501442a551ad92/SimpliSafe_Outdoor_Battery_Camera_Open_Source_Disclosures_Launch.DOCX
[root@ip-10-70-10-87 settings]# echo $?
4
[root@ip-10-70-10-87 settings]# wget -q --spider https://twitter.com/home
[root@ip-10-70-10-87 settings]# echo $?
0
```

- I checked the availability of proxy following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3807/how-to-check-if-network-proxy-is-really-applied#:%7E:text=%25-,env%20%7C%20grep%20%2Di%20proxy,-http_proxy%3Dhttp%3A//172.17.0.130) (i.e. `env | grep -i proxy`), and nothing came up as response, so I assume I've got no proxy configured

Comment: A work around could be to use `-k` flag with curl or `--no-check-certificate` with wget. It's not a solution!

Comment: Have you updated the O/S on your EC2?  It looks like your SSL info is old or bad.

Comment: First try updating the `openssl` package but I think you CA certificates may be broken in some way. Try following this guide to reset your list of trusted CA certificates - https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1549003

Comment: hi @Riz, I already tried adding both `-k` and `--no-check-certificate` to the curl & wget, yet both still returning the same error messages mentioned

Comment: @stdunbar how do I ensure if my OS is up to date? I'm sure that OS is monthly patched by the admin, but I just wanna make sure..

Comment: @Galih - run `sudo yum check-update` to see what needs updated.  Run `sudo yum update` to update them.

Comment: @Galih, for the moment if you just want to download sonar and don't want to worry about `ssl` issue, just download from `http`. Try (I tested and for me it works) `wget http://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-4.7.0.2747-linux.zip` .

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to update the OS and try to use the wget command without the -v flag like this:

```
wget https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-4.7.0.2747-linux.zi
```

you can also add `--no-check-certificate` or you can modify the ~/.wgetrc file and add

```
check_certificate = off
```

You can do this two things if you trust the host, hope this helps

Comment: Hi @TaylorBlackburn-292. first of all, how do I know if my OS is up to date? I'm pretty sure that the server got the OS patched monthly by the admin but I just want to make sure..

For removing the -v during wget, no it's still not working with the same error message as mentioned. Adding `--no-check-certificate` also still returned that error message of `Unable to establish SSL connection.`

Comment: You can check if your OS is up to date with this commands:
`sudo yum check-update`

`sudo yum update`

for the error that you are still getting check modifying the ~/.wgetrc file and add this line: 
 
`check_certificate = off`
I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

May I know if you are using any proxies for this ec2? If yes could you try to execute the wget command with `--no-proxy` option.

Found a similar issue in here, perhap its good to check for tls version compatibility as mentioned in the answers: [Unable to establish SSL connection upon wget on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757232/unable-to-establish-ssl-connection-upon-wget-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Comment: hi @Nanthini, I checked the availability of the proxy following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3807/how-to-check-if-network-proxy-is-really-applied#:~:text=%25-,env%20%7C%20grep%20%2Di%20proxy,-http_proxy%3Dhttp%3A//172.17.0.130), and nothing came up afterward, so I assume I've got no proxy used.. and for the tls version compatibility, I will check further for that